# Hide android keyboard on input focus

Tags: android

I have an input which is hidden from the view, Is there a way to stop an android device displaying the keyboard when focusing on the input?

Comment: you can use yourView..setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL); in onFocuschange listner of your inout view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want do disable focus only on androi device you have to detect user agent. You can use https://github.com/rafaelp/css_browser_selector. This plugin will add user agent to your html tag

```js
$('.android input').on('focus', function (e) {
   $(this).blur(); 
  e.preventDefault(); 
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `onCreate` function.

```
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

You can also do it from your manifest file. Inside the `<activity>` tag.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void hideSoftKeyboard(Activity activity) {
    if (activity.getCurrentFocus() != null) {
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
}

public static void hideSoftKeyboard(Fragment fragment) {
    if (fragment.getActivity().getCurrentFocus() != null) {
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) fragment.getActivity()
                .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(fragment.getActivity().getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: No where did you mention once either HTML or JS, just saying